# How to fetch Media(images) from wordpress site using JSON-API in android ?

Tags: android, json, wordpress, json-api

i want to load all the media contents, (images) in my wordpress site, to my android app using the JSON-API, i get it with retrieving the posts with JSON api, but what is with the images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by installing [WP REST API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/).

After the plugin is activated, make a GET request to `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media`. You will get all images info in JSON format.

[This article](http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/) might be helpful for you.

Make sure to change `example.com` to your actual domain.